# Windows 7 explorer textbox control

Tags: c#, wpf

Knows anyone of you a control, that looks like the text box in top of the windows 7 explorer?

[image: Windows 7 explorer textbox]

If there is no control like that, any suggestions how to write one?

André

Comment: Your comment was the hint I needed. Dont know why I could not find that post.